# What is the proper way to add a value to a list in a map?

Tags: flutter, save, maps

I am creating a Flutter app where I want the user to be able to add an event (String) to a List in a `Map (Map<DateTime, List<String>>)`. Then show them on the screen (later on a listView).

This is the class where the  Events and DatePicker are located:

```
class EventBrain {
  final Map<DateTime, List<String>> events = {};

  Future<Null> addEvent(BuildContext context, String title) async {
    final dtPick = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2019),
      lastDate: DateTime(2021),
    );
    if (events.containsKey(dtPick) == true) {
      events[dtPick].add(title);
      print(events[dtPick]);
    } else if (dtPick != null) {
      events.putIfAbsent(dtPick, () => <String>[]).add(title);
      print(events[dtPick]);
    }
  }
}
```

This is the screen where is expect it to print:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('ABC'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          EventBrain().addEvent(context, 'NewEvent');
        });
      }),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[Text(EventBrain().events.toString())],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you add an event or try to read the events from `EventBrain` you're creating a new instance when you'd want to use the same instance in each case.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _eventBrain = EventBrain();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('ABC'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () async {
        final dtPick = await showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          initialDate: DateTime.now(),
          firstDate: DateTime(2019),
          lastDate: DateTime(2021),
        );
        setState(() {
          _eventBrain.addEvent('NewEvent', dtPick);
        });
      }),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[Text(_eventBrain.events.toString())],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, I think it's good practice to keep context confined to your Widgets, this makes testing and code re-use a lot easier so your `EventBrain` class would look like this:

```
class EventBrain {
  final Map<DateTime, List<String>> events = {};

  Future<Null> addEvent(String title, DateTime dtPick) async {
    if (events.containsKey(dtPick) == true) {
      events[dtPick].add(title);
      print(events[dtPick]);
    } else if (dtPick != null) {
      events.putIfAbsent(dtPick, () => <String>[]).add(title);
      print(events[dtPick]);
    }
  }
}
```